# How to add Sass variable to Styled components in react js

Tags: reactjs, sass

I need to add sass variable to styled components in react js ,I have go through this link [Sass-extract-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-extract-js) and i have followed their procedure.

but i'm stuck in this line

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
background-color: ${p => p.theme.primary} //explain this line
`;
```

I have created var.scss file and contains

```
$black:#000000;
$white:#ffffff;
$red:#f64406;
$gray:#333333;
$green:#3bbd47;
```

In my render

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Welcome Back!</h2>
    <h3>Login Your Account</h3>
  </div>
```

Styled component

```
const Content = styled.div`
 h1:${}//how i can get variable here
 `;
```

Comment: Why would you like to declare sass variables in order to use them in CSS-inJS in the first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using theming in the styled-components. You can add variables to `ThemeProvider` as follows:

```
const theme = {
black:#000000,
white:#ffffff
red:#f64406
gray:#333333,
green:#3bbd47
}
<ThemeProvider theme={theme} >
    <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

and then this object can be used in the styled-components

```
const BlackDiv = styled`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.black}`;
```

For more info please check [theming](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced)

Comment: ok got it  i need to import that constant variable theme file in index .js file right ?

Comment: but i did like this

const theme = require(`sass-extract-loader?{
        "plugins": ["sass-extract-js"]
    }!./assets/css/var.scss`);

Comment: You can use npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-vars-to-js to extract sass variable to js object