# Can we override scss variables vai react props?Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4

Its been 2 whole days i can't find any solutions.I have no solutions yets:( I'm having color states. I'll select from color picker a color, I'll update that particular color state:
Requirement is if I pick from color picker it must be passed from react js property or variables to scss variable n override them. it must be done via reacrjs to scss if it can be done from js to css then it can be done from reacr js to scss whats that one thing which m missing on it.

App.js

```
{
  primary: '#1976D2',
  secondary: '#424242',
  accent: '#82B1FF',
  error: '#FF5252',
  info: '#2196F3',
  success: '#4CAF50',
  warning: '#FFC107'
}
```

ex: `primary: '#1976D2'` I'll pick in update to `primary: '#ffffff'` something like:

App.js

```
changeColor(e){
  this.setState({primary:e.target.value}) // the value is updated to #ffffff
}
```

Now, I need to pass `this.props.primary` to `.scss` something like:

variables.scss

```
$primary:this.props.primary
```

login.scss

```
.btn{ 
    background-color:$primary
 }
```

my need is it must be dynamic if i pick from color picker it must be passed from react js property or variables to scss variable n override them

We can do it inline styling but I wanna do it the way defined above (via .scss).
Is it possible?or is the any better way?

something like this

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme

vuejs uses theme thats overides to scss variables

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
 theme: {
primary: '#3f51b5',
secondary: '#b0bec5',
accent: '#8c9eff',
error: '#b71c1c'
 }
})
```

can anyone please explain me how they r doing I'm not understanding

Comment: scss is compiled ahead of runtime, what is react supposed to do about it as it can operate on runtime only? If you need variables at runtime, you'll have to take a look at CSS variables.

Comment: then how do i do something dynamically or any good option any good link for css variable at runtime to learn quick ?

Comment: As stated in the latter part of my comment.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491779/how-to-add-sass-variable-to-styled-components-in-react-js

Comment: @Zim i dont want sass-vars-to-js my need is i pick a color i.e., via js pass to sass

Comment: does your version of SASS compile variables as CSS custom properties?

Comment: yea it does. but my need is it must be dynamic if i pick from color picker it must be passed from react js property or variables to scss variable n override them

Comment: if sass variables are set as CSS custom properties you can just redefine any of them by JS regardless of Reactjs usage

Comment: @skyboyer requirement is if i pick from color picker it must be passed from react js property or variables to scss variable n override them. it must be done via reacrjs to scss if it can be done from js to css  then it can be done from reacr js to scss whats that one thing which m missing on it

Comment: I've check and I'm not sure if SASS can compile variables into custom properties out of box. Sorry for misinformation. But there is separate plugin for that: [css-vars](https://github.com/malyw/css-vars)

Answer (score 3):

First. Just to clarify. You are not able to change SASS variables from browser. Because how it works: SASS code -> compiled into CSS -> CSS is sent from server to browser -> . So we actually should searching "how to override by JS something that was SASS variable in consistent way".

The only way I see doing that is using CSS custom properties. Take a look into [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/) to understand their caveats(e.g. it cannot be used as part of size value in `@media`) and about [support in browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

I'm not really sure if SASS supports compiling variables into CSS custom properties. Take a look into [css-vars](https://github.com/malyw/css-vars) mixin. With using

```
$css-vars-use-native: true;
```

you will get your variables exported as CSS custom properties. *Unfortunately it means you need to change you existing styles to use `var()` from mixin for variables you want being able to override later*

Then your code will be able to override any of custom properties as easy as

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--primaryColor', myColorValueFromDatePicker)
```

Take a look into [fine and short article](https://vanseodesign.com/css/custom-properties-and-javascript/) on how to change custom properties with JS

NB since custom properties uses the same cascade approach as any CSS you additional get ability to apply changed value on any part of DOM:

```
document.querySelector('#previewBlock').style.setProperty(....);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Styled Components instead. There you can pass your styling by props

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: Or just styles defined in components

Comment: nope it must be dynamic if i pick from color picker it must be passed from js to scss variable n override them